# Hibernate Criteria unique result (column other than key)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm currently using a Hibernate Criteria to return a list of results (filtering on various column values), but several of the objects have the same value for one of the attributes and I only need one "representative" for each.

For example:  I am returned a list of 3 vehicle objects, with id/primary keys of 123, 456, 789, and manufacturer codes of: 111, 111, 222.  I'd like to only have returned a list with two objects:  123/111, 789/222.

Is there a way to add a restriction to a Hibernate Criteria in order to return only unique (or first) result of the manufacturer code in this example?  Please let me know if any additional info/clarification is needed.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491796/hibernate-group-by-criteria-object

above link is a good answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest approach is to implement an appropriate [`ResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) and apply it to your query.

If you really want it to be performed at the database side, you need some tricky query, such as this (in HQL/JPQL for brevity):

```
SELECT v FROM Vehicle v 
WHERE v.id = 
    (SELECT MIN(sv.id) FROM Vehicle sv WHERE sv.manufacturerCode = v.manufacturerCode)
```

Comment: This is the solution I wound up using.  I was hoping I could make it happen on the DB-side, but this works well for the small-ish (less than 10k) results typically retrieved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JPA with Hibernate the you can use something like below:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select cat from DomesticCat cat");
q.setMaxResults(1);
List cats = q.getResultList(); //return any one cat from matched rows
```

Now, just get the 1st Item from the list.
BTW, take care of NullPointerException and check the size of list before doing any further operation.

Else, if you are using **Hibernate without JPA**. You can go for the following one [**uniqueResult()**]:

```
Query query =session.createQuery("select ao from AccountOwner ao ");
AccountOwner ao=query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this will return only 1 record.  I'd like a list of all records, but limited to only one result per "manufacturer" from my example.

Comment: then, do not set the MaxResult/ do not go for UniqueResult, rather modify the query to add a 'group by' clause for 'manufacturer'.

Comment: How i know if i'm using with JPA (i'm using at the moment hibernate 4.2)?

Comment: @Diogo EntityManager.getDeletate() to find a provider:

em = emf.createEntityManager();
Object delegate = em.getDelegate();
if (delegate instanceof org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl)
System.out.println("Delegate: EclipseLink");
else if (delegate instanceof org.hibernate.Session)
System.out.println("Delegate: Hibernate");
else if (delegate instanceof org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl)
System.out.println("Delegate: OpenJPA");
else
System.out.println("Delegate: " + delegate);