# Hibernate Group by Criteria Object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I would like to implement the following SQL query with Hibernate Criteria:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name <operator> value
GROUP BY column_name
```

I have tried to implement this with Hibernate Criteria but it didn't work out.

Can anyone give me an example how this can be done with Hibernate Criteria?
Thanks!

Answer (score 91):

Please refer to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) for the example .The main point is to use the `groupProperty()` , and the related aggregate functions provided by the [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) class.

For example :

```sql
SELECT column_name, max(column_name) , min (column_name) , count(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name > xxxxx
GROUP BY column_name
```

Its equivalent criteria object is :

```
List result = session.createCriteria(SomeTable.class)       
                    .add(Restrictions.ge("someColumn", xxxxx))      
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.groupProperty("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.max("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.min("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.count("someColumn"))           
                    ).list();
```

Answer (score 17):

**GroupBy using in Hibernate**

This is the resulting code

```
public Map getStateCounts(final Collection ids) {
    HibernateSession hibernateSession = new HibernateSession();
    Session session = hibernateSession.getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DownloadRequestEntity.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("state"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    List results = criteria.list();
    Map stateMap = new HashMap();
    for (Object[] obj : results) {
        DownloadState downloadState = (DownloadState) obj[0];
        stateMap.put(downloadState.getDescription().toLowerCase() (Integer) obj[1]);
    }
    hibernateSession.closeSession();
    return stateMap;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the approach @Ken Chan mentions, and add a single line of code after that if you want a specific list of Objects, example:

```
    session.createCriteria(SomeTable.class)       
                    .add(Restrictions.ge("someColumn", xxxxx))      
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.groupProperty("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.max("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.min("someColumn"))
                            .add(Projections.count("someColumn"))           
                    ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SomeClazz.class));

List<SomeClazz> objectList = (List<SomeClazz>) criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do `group by` using hibernate criteria use `projections.groupPropery` like the following,

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(studentModel.class);
crit.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("studentName").as("name"))
List result = crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list(); 
return result;
```