# getting java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.criterion.PropertyProjection error

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I would like to implement the following SQL query with Hibernate Criteria:

```
select abc_id, count(*) from boa_rep_deed where sync_system = ? And hook_id = ? group by abc_id order by abc_id
```

what I have tried is this ...

```
List<teedObject> hytlow = null;
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("abcID ", abcID));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));

        hytlow = criteria.list();
```

Now my question is I have the corresponding pojo for this also as shown below..

```
class teedObject
{

    private long abcID ;
    private String syncSystem ;
    private String hookId;

    //and consisits other properties and setters and getters

}
```

Now I want my criteria to fetch only certain columns in order to make the object lighter so for that I have to use the projections in the criteria , can you please advise how to use projections in my case in order to fetch only certain coulmns , I have tried this..

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));
cr.addOrder(Order.asc("abcID"));
cr.add(Projections.groupProperty("abcID")));
cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
hytlow = cr.list();
```

but it is throwing the exception as ..
`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.criterion.PropertyProjection`.. can you please advise have I implemented the projections in an correct manner

Answer (score 0):

```
        List result = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class)       
                .add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId))
                .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("abcID"))
                        .add(Projections.count("abcID"))           
                ).list();
```

see [Hibernate Group by Criteria Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491796/hibernate-group-by-criteria-object)

Comment: thanks but how I would implement this in my case, please explain.

Comment: I did not get it I have tried this..
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));
cr.addOrder(Order.asc("abcID"));
cr.add(Projections.groupProperty("abcID")));
cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
hytlow = cr.list();

Comment: but upon implementing the above i am getting the error pls advise

Comment: replace "setProjection(Projections.rowCount());" with "setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(..." and then add everything from your select clause

Comment: I could not grasp still, request you to please post the modified code , that will help me to grasp the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please advise can I w\start with this form also..Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class); as I want it to start it in similiar fashion of query as I have started it please advise

Comment: @Leoi here result is not of criteria type

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46099/discussion-between-leo-and-user1633823)

Answer (score 0):

any Projections you add. It saves it as an array of objects. c.list(); The returned data type is actually a Projections array.

Example code:

```
        Criteria c;
        ProjectionList projectionList=Projections.projectionList();
        projectionList.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("salary"), "sum"));
        projectionList.add(Projections.avg("salary"), "avg");
        c.setProjection(projectionList);

        //list example 1
        for(Object[] o : (List<Object[]>) c.list())
        {
            System.out.println(o[0]);
            System.out.println(o[1]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        List<?> results = c.list();
        results.forEach(s -> {
            //list example2
            for(Object o:(Object[])s)
            {
                System.out.println(o);
            }
            //list example3
            System.out.println();
            Object[] o=(Object[]) s;
            System.out.println(o[0]);
            System.out.println(o[1]);
        });
```