# Hibernate Criteria with condition on count

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I need the equivalent of

```
SELECT m.id, count(i.id)
FROM master m LEFT JOIN item i on m.id = i.master_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.size
HAVING m.size <> count(i.id);
```

in Hibernate Criteria. Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8494814/581205), I know how to get the grouped result as a list of `Object[]`:

```
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("master"));
projList.add(Projections.count("id"));

session
.createCriteria(Item.class)
.join("master")
.setProjection(projList)
.addRestriction(???) // <- my HAVING clause
.list();
```

I have no clue how to add the HAVING clause. I guess, it's something like `Restrictions.eqProperty`, but how can I refer to the count?

Is there a way how to refer to the resulting tuple elements in the query?

Comment: how can m.size be in your having clause without being in the group by clause ?

Comment: @jpprade It's MySQL. :D MySQL is rather sloppy in this respect and I forgot to switch the strict mode on. Another thing is that with `id` being the PK, mentioning the `size` in GROUP BY is redundant (logically, not according to SQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate Criteria API does not support `HAVING` clauses. Since it is deprecated anyway in newer Hibernate versions, I suggest you move to JPA Criteria API, or use HQL/JPQL or more advanced wrappers like [Querydsl JPA](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sqlRestriction how workaround, something like:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1 group by this_.id, this_.size HAVING this_.size <> count(i_.id));
```

Here is a example:

```
ct.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection(
                    "cobr_.client_id as clientID"
                    , new String[] {"clientID" }
                    , new Type[] { new LongType()}));
ct.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1 group by cobr_.vlr_total,clientID having (sum(this_.vlr_net)-cobr_.vlr_total) < -20"));
```

Comment: That's kind of SQL injection for the greater good. :D Ugly like hell, but +1.