# Use Hibernate Criteria API to return first row of each group

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to write a criteria query to return the latest status of employee on a given date

```
id  |   Status  | status_date
1   |   Active  |   1/10/2017
2   |   Active  |   1/10/2017
...
1   |   Inactive|   5/10/2017
...
1   |   Active  |   9/10/2017
```

So I will be passing a date to the query and want to find the latest status of every employee on that date
The expected result will be something like this

Example: For date 6/1/2017, this will be the returned data

```
id  |   Status  |   Date
1   |   Inactive|   5/10/2017
2   |   Active  |   1/10/2017
```

I was able to add group by with id and order the rows by status date in descending order. Is there a way I can select only the top row for each group? I tried to use the max function on status_date but that does not work.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = builder.createQuery(Employee);
Root<Employee> root = cq.from(Employee.class);
cq.select(root);
cq.groupBy(root.get("id"));
cq.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("status_date")));
cq.having(builder.max(root.get("status_date")));
```

Comment: This similar question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491796/hibernate-group-by-criteria-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to output aggregation, not use aggregation as condition so you should not place it in `having` clause. You must add the aggregation to selection list instead.

First you must create aggregation result class (It's usual to different to your entity class):

```
public static class StatusEntityResult {
    private String userId;
    private String status;
    private Date statusDate;
    // getter, setter, constructor with all parameters here
}
```

Then create a query using it as result:

```
public List<StatusEntityResult> queryStatus() throws ParseException {
    // Date condition
    Date targetDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-10-06");

    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // Use StatusEntityResult as result
    CriteriaQuery<StatusEntityResult> cq = builder.createQuery(StatusEntityResult.class);
    Root<Employee> root = cq.from(Employee.class);

    // Select `id`, `status` and `max(status_date)`
    cq.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("status"), builder.max(root.get("statusDate")))
            .where(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("statusDate"), targetDate))
            .groupBy(root.get("id"))
            .orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("statusDate")));

    return this.entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

**Side note**

From what you wrote, you was attempting to use `JPA Criteria`, not `Hibernate Criteria`.  For `Hibernate Criteria` solution, you can try to read `@default locale` suggestion