# Hibernate SQL findin most often appearing number?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

I have a joint table of user id and test that they took id.
How can I write Hibernate query that shows which test was taken most often?

In this case I just need to get number 1 as a result:

```
user_id     test_id
23          1
24          1
25          1
53          32
76          32 
77          1 
78          1
```

Comment: You can use a groupby criteria -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491796/hibernate-group-by-criteria-object and then count by it.

Answer (score 1):

try the below HQL Query

```
String HQL = "
SELECT       test_id
    FROM     `your_table`
    GROUP BY test_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT    1";
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well in PostgreSQL, although Hibernate didn't understand the limit part. I just took 1st result from the list.

Answer (score -1):

Try to select the max value:

```
String HQL = "select max(test_id) from my_entity";
Query query = sess.createQuery(HQL);
List list = query.list();
System.out.println("Max is " + list.get(0));
```

Comment: Max value gives the biggest number, in this case 32